# Getting error No Tests found with test runner Junit in cucumber+JVM using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I was trying to run Cucumber scenarios using cucumber JVM but I was getting "No tests found with Junit 4" I am not using maven at the moment.

I have written following step definition

```
    package stepd;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import pageobject.PageObject;
   import cucumber.api.java.After;
   import cucumber.api.java.Before;
   import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
   import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
   import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
   public class StepDefinition
   {
    private PageObject po;
    private WebDriver driver;
    public StepDefinition(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
        po=new PageObject(driver);
    }
    @Given("^I navigate to the mock application$")
    public void given_I_navigate_to_the_mock_application()
    {
        driver.get("http://demo.crowdperks.com/crowdperks");
    }
    @When("^I click login link$")
    public void when_I_click_login_link()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("signup")).click();
    }

    @Then("^I should see Login page$")
    public void then_I_login()
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("cplive");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("cplive");
    }
   }
```

Also when running from test runner file i.e. GenericTest I am not getting run as junit option in the context menu

Please provide help

Comment: Double check your class paths. If you have issues with configurations class, show it rather displaying other classes.

Comment: @karthikeyan The path is correct. Can u elaborate more on this

Comment: How are you running your tests?